# db_add_field not working

Tags: 7, database

I want to add a new field to `node`  table using [db_add_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_field/7) when intalling a new module, but it seems there is something wrong or missing:

here is the code used:

```
/**
* Implements hook_schema_alter()
*/
function smart_delete_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  // Add field to existing schema.
  $schema['node']['fields']['show_in_inbox'] = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'length' => '4',
    'default' => '1',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'unsigned' => TRUE,  
    'description' => 'Field added by Smart_delete module',
  ); 
}

/**
* Implements hook_install()
*/
function smart_delete_install(){
    if (!db_field_exists('node', 'show_in_inbox')) {
        $schema = drupal_get_schema('node');
        db_add_field('node', 'show_in_inbox', $schema['fields']['show_in_inbox']);
    }
}
```

**ADD :**

I made an db_query in `hook_init()` inside .module file :

```
$result = db_query("ALTER TABLE `node` ADD `show_in_inbox` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';");
```

this is working, but the same db_query in .install file is not working when disable/enable the module again!

(I cleared the cache, also add the file in .info file)

Comment: Wait, you are _uninstalling_ the module, not just disabling it right? `hook_install()` only gets fired when installing, not just enabling

Comment: Is there a difference between installing and disabling, then enabling again the module ? what I made is just going to modules, disable smart_delete module and enable it again! is that not enough ?

Comment: Not quite, you also need to go to the uninstall tab and actually uninstall it - two different things in Drupal 7 :) Or, if it makes more sense, you could put your code in `hook_enable/hook_disable`

Comment: Never heard about this before, sounds good Clive, I'll try and go back to you, thx a lot for info :)

Comment: Thanks again Clive it's working after uninstalling the module ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `length` is valid for integers. `size` is though:

```
$schema['node']['fields']['show_in_inbox'] = array(
  'type' => 'int',
  'size' => 'tiny',
  'default' => '1',
  'not null' => TRUE,
  'unsigned' => TRUE,  
  'description' => 'Field added by Smart_delete module',
);
```

[Data Types](http://drupal.org/node/159605)

Comment: I Tried also, dosen't work :(

Comment: I have added in question other indication that not working in .install file